# Buy old currency in Bratislava and Vienna

Tags: austria, vienna, slovakia, nostalgia, bratislava

I will be traveling to Bratislava and Vienna this week. I want to know if there are any shops where I would get the old Slovak Korunas or Austrian Schillings. Also, I stay in Munich. Are there any places to get old Deutsche Mark.

Preferably Banknotes!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every capital city I have ever been, and many smaller cities and towns, have shops selling coins, and those mostly also do bank notes of the country.
In German, for Vienna and Germany, you google on 'Münze' or of course 'shops Coins or Numismatics' (leave off the last few letters and google will fill it out for you.

I can not find the Slovak word as fast, is seems to be 'mince' (which might give confusing results on English language search sites) or 'minca' or 'minci' which are less likely to be used in the name of shops, so if you search on "koruna" and "halier" (the name of the coins they used to use) you will likely also find the right shops.

I find two shops for Vienna, that does not mean there are not more, it is just a first, general, search. 
Münzen-Zentrum
Auerspergstraße 5, 1080 Wien

Münze Österreich
Am Heumarkt 1, 1030 Wien

For Bratislava I found this one:
Coin and Stamp Collecting Shop
Majkova 2 (Avion building, walking distance from downtown Bratislava)
Again, likely one of more, maybe even many.

As the Euro in Slovakia is relatively new and in Austria not that much older if you see it in the light of the whole history, you might even find the old money in souvenir shops, in ready filled packs with a nice collection. I do not remember having seen those packets in those countries, I do remember them from my home country.

How much you need to pay depends on whether the money can still be exchanged for euros, and of course, the rarety and the condition of said money.

I have used [this site for Slovakia](http://www.slovak-republic.org/shopping/), and [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=coin%20shop%20vienna) for Vienna.

Comment: For Austria, Schillings (notes and coins) can be still be exchanged. More detailled: The last design/version of the Schillings (mostly since 1983) can be exchanged without any known time limit (for now); older Schilling [which partially still could be used before the Euro] can't be exchanged anymore. 500 and 1000 Schilling notes changed one time after 1983 too, the old ones can be exchanged until April 2018. https://www.oenb.at/Bargeld/umtausch-in-euro/Schilling.html